# Can you see if a card was created by an Unstable Portal or Webspinner in the log?

Tags: hearthstone

As you may know Hearthstone has an output_log.txt, which you can enable in the log.config. Here you can see a whole bunch of information about the game, which cards have been played and so on. Is there a way to see if a card was created by another card's effect, such as Unstable Portal or Webspinner? I know that you can obviously do this by looking at the card in-game, but I need to read it from the log, if possible.

I know this is a long shot, but if anyone has some information or ideas on this, please let me know.

Comment: It's not marked on the in-game log, so I'd be surprised if it was logged in the output_log.txt file. I'll try to test for sure when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty simple, as long as you know the trick. Card played have an ID in the zone log and if that ID is above 67, the card was created by some other card or effect. This won't work if the card is played, returned to the hand, then played again, but there might be an easy way to track this as well. If nothing else, you could still track the position of the card in the hand.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with 100% certainty BUT there is this application called [Deck Tracker](https://github.com/Epix37/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker) which uses the in game log files to give you all sorts of useful information. When someone plays unstable portal or thoughtsteal or webspinner (etc) you can see a little gift icon on the card which means that there is enough info in the logs for you to know that this is a bonus card.

Also Blizzard has now made it so when your opponent plays a card like that you see a message under it that states where he got it from. For example: "Created by Unstable Portal".

Other than that I can't be sure. But you could also try contacting the creators of Deck Tracker because if someone knows for sure (other than Blizzard ofc) its them! :)

Comment: I actually ended up doing something like this, some days ago. They were very helpful and I got an answer to my question.